# Design pattern for specialized properties in subclasses

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, subclass

***Duplicate of [C# Accessing a subclass property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073611/c-sharp-accessing-a-subclass-property) - see additional solution approaches there.***

I have an object model where each object has a parent and I would like  to access the parent property with the specific type for each object. So e.g. Wheel shall have a parent property of type Car. My guess is that there is an established design pattern for achieving this (in .NET). However, I have not found it so the design I came up with looks like this

```
public class BaseObject<T> where T : BaseObject<T>
{
    private T mParent;
    protected T Parent
    {
        get { return mParent; }
    }

    public BaseObject(T parent)
    {
        mParent = parent;
    }

    public void Save() ...
    public void Delete() ...
    public BaseObject<T> Clone() ...
}

public class Car : BaseObject<Car>
{
    public Car(Car parent) : base(parent)
    {
    }

    public bool Is4WD()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Wheel : BaseObject<Car>
{
    public Wheel(Car parent) : base(parent)
    {
    }

    public float RequiredTirePressure()
    {
        return Parent.Is4WD() ? 3.0f : 2.5f;
    }
}
```

Do you see any design or performance drawbacks with this approach? Can you recommend a better design?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Jungling with generics is seldom a good idea.

Comment: My data consists of an object tree with a main object that may have child objects which in turn may have own children etc. To accomplish this each object has a reference to its parent where it may register/unregister. In many cases the child object accesses its parent's methods/properties. One way is to cast the parent property from the base type to the right type but I was wondering if there is a way for a type-safe declaration.

Comment: Liskovs Substitution Principle says that any method which takes the base class should work with all different subclasses. What you are asking is a violation of that principle and therefore not a true `is-a` relationship. It would better if you could illustrate your problem with real class names instead of the abstract names you have added now.

Comment: I tried to make the example more meaningful by using specific class names (sorry I cannot use real names here). Does this make clear what I am looking for?

Comment: No. I do not get the usage of "BaseObject". What's the point?

Comment: Some base functions are implemented here, like Save, Delete, Clone. Sorry for the suboptimal example, I added this to the code.

Comment: Why do the basetype need to know the type that implements it?

Comment: As far as I see it doesn't. BaseObject has no reference to Car or Wheel, has it?

Comment: `BaseObject<Car>` I call that together with `public Car(Car parent) : base(parent)` a reference. imho you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: BaseObject uses its parent reference to access base functions (e.g. change notification). In subclasses I would like to use the parent reference to access methods of the specific type.

Comment: Like I said from the beginning. You are violating LSP if you design your app like that. You are trying to create a generic approach where the objects really do not have a relation to each other. If a class needs a specific parent, use that parent and not a generic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use [composition instead of inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). A wheel is not a car, so it should not extend from `Car`. Instead, have the `Wheel` take a `Car` in its constructor.

For example:

```
public class Wheel {
    private Car car;

    public Wheel(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public float RequiredTirePressure() {
        return car.Is4WD() ? 3.0f : 2.5f;
    }
}
```

- [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Makes sense what you are saying. I guess what I had in mind was something like [Rockford Lhotka's CSLA .NET framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Default.aspx). He has a class BusinessBase with some base functionality from which other classes inherit (in my example Wheel also extends BaseObject and not Car). The parent property is of type IParent. Would you suggest to cast IParent to the specific type in this case?

Comment: I'll go with your suggestion to use a reference of a specific type with the child objects (in addition to a reference in the base object). Yet, I must admit I am not fully buying into completely abandoning inheritance used in a way that seems to be accepted, e.g. in the CSLA .NET framework.