# C# Accessing a subclass property

Tags: c#, .net, properties, polymorphism

I have a few classes and I am having problems accessing properties defined in subclasses from other class methods.

I have a base class called `Section` and a few subclasses, e.g. `SectionPlane : Section`. In each subclass, a different set of fields and properties are defined (in `SectionPlane`, private field `_t` and public property `t` can be found, whereas in `SectionExtruded : Section` I have private field `_A` and public property ´A´).

**Class Section**

```
// General section object
public abstract class Section
{
    public Section()
    {}
}
```

**Class Plane Section**

```
// Section object representing a plane with thickness t
public class SectionPlane : Section
{
    private double _t;

    public SectionPlane(double t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public double t
    {
        get
        {
            return _t;
        }
        set
        {
            _t = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class Extruded Section**

```
// Section object of some geometry with cross section area A extruded along the element it is assigned to.
public class SectionExtruded : Section
{
    private double _A;

    public SectionExtruded(double A)
    {
        this.A = A;
    }

    public double A
    {
        get
        {
            return _A;
        }
        set
        {
            _A = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I from any subclass of the class `Element` tries to access the properties, since theese are not set in the base class `Section`, e.g. in the element `Solid2D : Element`:

**Class Element**

```
public abstract class Element
{
    private Section _section;

    public Element(Section section)
    {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public Section section
        {
            get 
            {
                return _section;
            }
            set
            {
                _section = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Class Solid 2D Element**

```
// Solid2D elements can only have sections of type SectionPlane
public class Solid2D : Element
{
    public Solid2D(SectionPlane section)
        : base(section)
    {
    }

    public void Calc()
    {
        double t = section.t;    // This results in error 'Section' does not contain a definition for 't' and no extension method 't' accepting a first argument of type 'Section' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    }
}
```

**Bar Element**

```
// Bar elements can only have sections of type SectionExtruded
public class Solid2D : Element
{
    public Solid2D(SectionExtruded section)
        : base(section)
    {
    }

    public void Calc()
    {
        double A = section.A;    // This results in error 'Section' does not contain a definition for 'A' and no extension method 'A' accepting a first argument of type 'Section' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to access my property `t` without having to include it in the base class `Section`? This would be very helpfull since not all of the sections that I will use have the same properties.

Comment: To access `SectionPlane` properties you must first convert the object type to `SectionPlane`.  Tim S. said it first, but Olivier Jacot-Descombes post is much more clear on the matter.

Comment: I had the same question a few weeks ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804578/design-pattern-for-specialized-properties-in-subclasses) and I must say you gave an excellent explanation of the problem far better than mine. Anyway, my solution was to add a field `SectionPlane sectionPlane` to `Solid2D` and initialize it in the constructor. In my case this was sufficient since it was readonly. You might need to override the property `section` (setter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you know that it can only be a `SectionPlane` you can cast it

```
double t = ((SectionPlane)section).t;
```

If you are not sure whether you have a section of the right type, you can use the `as` keyword

```
double t = 0;
var sectionPane = section as SectionPlane;
if (sectionPane != null) {
    t = sectionPane.t;
}
```

`as` does not throw an exception if the section has another type, but returns `null` instead.

Or you can simply test

```
double t = 0;
if(section is SectionPlane) {
    t = ((SectionPlane)section).t;
}
```

but this is less elegant than using `as`, since you have to test the type and then cast it; but casting does this test again internally.

Using the new pattern matching introduced in C# 7.0 you can write:

```
double t = 0;
if(section is SectionPlane sp) {
    t = sp.t;
}
```

---

But if you have to perfrom such a test, the question is, whether your approach is right in the object-oriented sense. If you move the `Calc`-method to the abstract class `Section` and let each class perform its own calculation, then no type test or casting will be required.

In `Section`:

```
public abstract void Calc();
```

In `SectionPlane`

```
public override void Calc()
{
    var x = t;
}

...

section.Calc();  // No casting or type test required.
```

Comment: But that would be a patch right, not the optimum way to model it. But then again without knowing what "t" actually represents, it is hard to tell a better model.

Comment: Thanks! Tried to cast before, but missed a few brackets that did the magic =)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, to put your property "t" in the Section base class, if that belongs there.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

1. Change `Element.section` to a `SectionPlane`.
2. Cast `section` to `SectionPlane` in `Calc()`.
3. Add `t` to `Section`.
4. Make an interface (e.g. `IHasT`) that has the `t` property, make `SectionPlane` implement this, and change `Element.section` to `IHasT`.
5. (if applicable) change `public abstract class Element` to `public abstract class Element<T> where T : Section`, change `section` to type `T`, and make `Solid2D : Element<SectionPlane>`

Comment: Thank's for your reply!
1. Not possible, since not all Elements will use the SectionPlane.
 2. I have tried this whithout luck.
 3. As I mentioned, not what I want.
 4. Can you develop this option? I don't understand how I could change `Element.section` to `IHasT`
 5. Will try and see what consequences this gives to the rest of the code

Comment: They are separate possibilities, not an in-order list of a single solution, so check out 2-5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of section the element inheritors will use, I'd make the element base class a generic:

```
 public abstract class Element<SectionType>
     where SectionType:Section
 {
    //....
 }
```

You could include a default element type, by using the base class:

```
 public abstract class Element:Element<Section>
 {
    //....
 }
```

And the known elements could inherit strongly typed:

```
 public class Solid2D : Element<SectionPlane>
```